# asp.net webapi mapping a string param that has a querystring

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I need to map a string param with a webapi method. Something easy:

```
/api/mycontroller/this_is_my_input_param
```

I know how to do it and it's working fine. However, problem is that my input param can have a query string. Something like:

```
/api/mycontroller/term?p=1&n=value
```

and I want that webapi map the entire "term?p=1&n=value" with the input param in the method. I just wanna tell webapi "ey, just take all the string you have after /api/mycontroller/ and send it to the action as input parameter"

I know that probably is not the best architectural thing, but I need it that way. Also, I don't know how many params and names I can have, so I can't use a complex type. I also need it as a GET. I know how to do it with a POST, but I need a GET if it's possible.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you able to add that querystring to body and then by using (frombody/ fromuri) attributes
to grab the querystring and do whatever you want

`Route[api/mycontroller/term] 
public HttpResponseMessage myController([fromBody] querystring)
{`
// do something for that querystring

`}`

please check webapi attributes from this link
[enter link description here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. It's a valid approach, but I'd like not to use the Body and do it all in the URL. Reason is that actually, the webapi is just a proxy to another service that I don't have any control, and now, I already have quite a lot JS code that is calling the existing service, and I'd like just to change the URL to call the new webapi service, keeping the most existing JS code that I already have. Is there any other option??

Comment: not sure if I explain well. I mean that now I have a lot of jQuery.Ajax calls to the current service with the URLs like I said in the question, and I'd like just to change the base URL pointing to the new webapi "proxy". If I use the FromBody, I need to update the jQuery.Ajax calls to set the querystring in the Body of the call. Makes sense? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally what I'm doing is mapping the entire HttpRequest, that way I can work with the full requestted URL and get all that I have after the Controller name:

```
public async Task<string> Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
```

I know would be better to create a custom ModelBinder or something like that, but in my case is enough doing it that way.

thanks for your help.

Comment: okay thats cool. you can probably try predicates also to parse the query strings .